# Iif statement and select subquery inside update query Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, iif

I am working on a database to help me keep track of employee leave and attendance records.  I created an Employees table, with the list of employees and the yearly leave balances that roll forward from the previous year.  I then made a Leave Records table that lists the leave accrued and used for each pay period.  I can use a formula to calculate the leave balance forward automatically once the leave balance forward for that pay period has been entered.  What I'm having trouble with is getting the database to automatically calculate the leave balance that rolls forward.  The balance will change for each pay period, however what the value needs to be is the leave balance total for the same employee in the previous pay period.

I have the following SQL in a select query and it works:

```
A/L Bal Fwd: IIf([Leave Records].[Pay Period]=1,[Employees].[Yearly A/L Bal Fwd],(SELECT [Leave Records].[A/L Balance to Date] 
FROM [Leave Records] AS Dupe 
WHERE Dupe.Employee = [Leave Records].Employee
AND Dupe.[Pay Period] = [Leave Records].[Pay Period]-1)) AS [A/L Bal Fwd]
FROM Employees INNER JOIN [Leave Records] ON Employees.ID = [Leave Records].Employee;
```

The issue now is that any pay period beyond #1 it will not return a value unless data has been entered into the [Leave Records] table.  My goal is to find a way to have access automatically calculate the value in [Leave Records].[A/L Bal Fwd] to save time from having to calculate that same field every pay period for 56 employees.  I tried running an update query with the Iif statement above, but it only returned blank values.  I'm trying to avoid creating temporary tables and having too many queries to run to have it update each pay period as much as possible.  The fewer steps I have to take for these values to update and be correct each pay period, the better.

Comment: you need to modify the INNER join to the LEFT join. That way the record will always be there but for the [Leave Records] entries you will have nulls. You will need to handle the nulls using IsNULL() function: `IIf(ISNULL([Leave Records].[Pay Period]) OR [Leave Records].[Pay Period]=1`

Comment: I tried adding the null function as well as the LEFT join, and it gave me an error message saying that the JOIN Expression is not supported.